# Modify a shell variable inside awk block of code

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

Is there any way to modify a shell variable inside awk block of code?

```
--------- [shell_awk.sh]---------------------
 #!/bin/bash

shell_variable_1=<value A>
shell_variable_2=<value B>
shell_variable_3=<value C>

awk 'function A(X)
{ return X+1 }
{ a=A('$shell_variable_1')
  b=A('$shell_variable_2')
  c=A('$shell_variable_3')
  shell_variable_1=a
  shell_variable_2=b
  shell_variable_3=c
}' FILE.TXT
--------- [shell_awk.sh]---------------------
```

This is a very simple example, the real script load a file and make some changes using functions, I need to keep each value before change into a specific variable, so then I can register into MySQL the before and after value.

The after value is received from parameters ($1, $2 and so on).

The value before I already know how to get it from the file.

All is done well, except the shell_variable been set by awk variable. Outside from awk block code is easy to set, but inside, is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No program -- in awk, shell, or any other language -- can directly modify a parent process's memory. That includes variables. However, of course, your `awk` can write contents to stdout, and the parent shell can read that content and modify its own variables itself.

---

Here's an example of awk that writes key/value pairs out to be read by bash. It's not perfect -- read the caveats below.

```
#!/bin/bash

shell_variable_1=10
shell_variable_2=20
shell_variable_3=30

run_awk() {
        awk -v shell_variable_1="$shell_variable_1" \
            -v shell_variable_2="$shell_variable_2" \
            -v shell_variable_3="$shell_variable_3" '
        function A(X) { return X+1 }
        { a=A(shell_variable_1)
          b=A(shell_variable_2)
          c=A(shell_variable_3) }
        END {
          print "shell_variable_1=" a
          print "shell_variable_2=" b
          print "shell_variable_3=" c
        }' <<<""
}

while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
        printf -v "$key" '%s' "$value"
done < <(run_awk)

for var in shell_variable_{1,2,3}; do
  printf 'New value for %s is %s\n' "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

---

#### Advantages

- Doesn't use `eval`. Content such as `$(rm -rf ~)` in the output from `awk` won't be executed by your shell.

#### Disadvantages

- Can't handle variable contents with newlines. (You could fix this by NUL-delimiting output from your `awk` script, and adding `-d ''` to the `read` command).
- A hostile awk script could modify `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or other security-sensitive variables. (You could fix this by reading variables into an associative array, rather than the global namespace, or by enforcing a prefix on their names).
- The code above uses several ksh extensions also available in bash; however, it will *not* run with POSIX sh. Thus, be sure not to run this via `sh scriptname` (which only guarantees POSIX functionality).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will adapt into my script and make some tests, as soon as possible I'll return the results

Comment: It works well your script, was a very nice model.

Unfortunately, my script need to load a file, and by column position (not delimiter position), so to do the trick I needed to use read to open file by FD, read line by line, and then use it with printf -v of your read example, all that separeted by funcitons.

I tried to do a simple example, but I failed, and my final script is protected by law, reason why I just explained without code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't need that sort of workaround: The entire reason I put the `print`s in the `END` statement was to run them only *after* you were finished processing lines in any input file. You *did* remove the `<<<""` when replacing it with the redirection from your input file, right?

Comment: By the way, if you were to end up calling `awk` once per line of input, I'd suggest that you'd be better off implementing your processing in native bash instead. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 to get started with some of the kinds of operations one might otherwise look first at `awk` for.